# Correctly embedding Powerpoint into wordpress - iFrame window size and resolution

Tags: html, iframe, powerpoint

I am aiming to embed a Powerpoint presentation into Wordpress through a custom HTML code block. The code is below

`<iframe src="https://1drv.ms/p/c/c9e3bb227cc0e980/IQP62rxqq86CT40mpJMUOXkAAZ5g5dEEWEDRRFjjuUuZ8Ig?em=2&amp;wdAr=1.7777777777777777&amp;wdEaaCheck=1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">This is an embedded <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com">Microsoft Office</a> presentation, powered by <a target="_blank" href="https://office.com/webapps">Office</a>.</iframe>`

The problem is that the inserted window does not fit the window (Figure 1 below). If I manually set the width and height to fit the window by the code below, the view panel fits but slides themselves are low resolution (Figure 2).

`width="952px" height="576px"`

What I need is to have the presentation fill the entire width of the window WITH high original slide resolution.

Based on this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzzxmp5HM68), that is possible - although the author was using Wix.

Figure 1
[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2
[image: Figure 2]